# Is there an arithmetic mean limit on the symmetrical items of the harmonic series?

Tags: limits, logarithms, harmonic-numbers, music-theory

Is it possible to determine what is the arithmetic mean of the harmonic series where $n$ and $-n$ are added and divided by two in this manner:

$$f(n) = \frac{
(\frac{3}{4})^n \times 2^{⌈-n \times log_2(\frac{3}{4})⌉} + 
(\frac{3}{4})^{-n} \times 2^{⌈n \times log_2(\frac{3}{4})⌉}
}{2}$$

For each positive plus negative whole number $n$ we have an arithmetic mean. See values in the continuous graph below:

[image]

Now I want to sum them and take an average something like:

$$\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{x}{f(n)}}{x}$$

Does this series converge, if x is infinity?

My preliminary spreadsheet calculation gives a value somewhere near to $(6/5)^2 = 1.44$ if $n$ is $20$. Or, maybe a cuberoot of three? See row 20 in the picture. But I'm missing tools to determine if this equation has a limit when $n$ is a whole number approaching infinity?

#### Possible limit equation

$$
\lim_{h \to \infty}{\frac{1}{h}\sum_{n=1}^{h}{
\frac{
(\frac{3}{4})^n \times 2^{⌈-n \times log_2(\frac{3}{4})⌉} + 
(\frac{3}{4})^{-n} \times 2^{⌈n \times log_2(\frac{3}{4})⌉}
}{2}
}}
$$

With Wolfram Alpha I got the summation formula simplified to:

$$g(n) = \frac{2^{-\frac{n\log\frac{4}{3}}{\log2}\pmod1} + 2^{\frac{n \log\frac{4}{3}}{\log2}\pmod1}}{2}$$

The distribution of the first 500 values in graph looks like this:

[image: 500 values of the average of symmetric harmonized 3/4 series]

#### Spreadsheet

[image: Harmonic series]

Col 7 is (col3+col4)/2 corresponding equation in my question. Cols 3, 4, 7 are points (x, y) but x only is applicable now. Col 1 and 2 are positive and negative $n$.

#### Added references

This seems to relate to Cesaro mean:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation

[Cesàro means of conditionally convergent series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1315672/ces%C3%A0ro-means-of-conditionally-convergent-series)

Comment: The term you write is always $1$, independent of $n$. What did you calculate in your spreadsheet?

Comment: @Kusma I thought that as well at first, but those aren't brackets, those are floor functions

Comment: Col 7 is (col3+col4)/2 corresponding equation in my question. Cols 3,4,7 are points (x,y) but x only is applicable now. Col 1 and 2 are positive and negative n. And yes, there are ceil functions in powers of two.

Comment: Are you intentionally summing $n+1$ values but then only dividing by $n$?

Comment: Good point. I should probably start with n=1. Then two symmetric values are added in summation and divided by two. And the final set of summated values should be divided by top index to get the average.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer is $\frac12\int_0^1 (2^x+2^{1-x})dx = \frac{1}{\log2}\approx 1.44269504$. This follows from the [equidistribution theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistribution_theorem) (look for Khinchin's integral and apply to the functions $f_1(x)=2^x$ and  $f_2(x)=2^{1-x}$).

With some more steps, we have $(\frac34)^n=2^{n \log_2 \frac34}$ so $$
(\frac34)^n 2^{\lceil -n\log_2 \frac34 \rceil} = 2^{n\log_2 \frac34+\lceil -n\log_2 \frac34 \rceil}
$$
and $$(\frac34)^{-n} 2^{\lceil n\log_2 \frac34 \rceil} = 2^{-n\log_2 \frac34+\lceil n\log_2 \frac34 \rceil}.
$$
Now for $x\notin\mathbb{Z}$, $x+\lceil -x\rceil = x \bmod 1$ and $-x+\lceil{x}\rceil=(1-x) \bmod 1=1+(-x \bmod 1)$.

Set $\alpha=\log_2{\frac34} = \log_23-2$. Then $\alpha$ is irrational because otherwise, you'd have $3=2^{\frac pq}$ for integers $p$ and $q$, so $3^q=2^p$, clearly impossible.

So we are calculating 
$$\frac1{2N} \sum_{n=1}^N \left(2^{(n\alpha \bmod 1)}+ 2^{1+(-n\alpha \bmod 1)}\right)
$$

Khinchin's identity now says that by the irrationality of $\alpha$, the limit is 
$$\frac12\int_0^1 \left(2^{x}+2^{1-x}\right) dx = \frac1{2\ln 2}\left[2^x-2^{1-x} \right]_0^1
=\frac1{2\ln2}(2-1-1+2)=\frac{1}{\ln 2}.
$$

Comment: At least the first five decimals match when taking the average of 1000 and 10000 values of the function. But precision seems to get better very slowly, there are jumps back and forth toward the expected value when iterations increase. I altered the ceil function of the equation to the mod and got better results in Wolfram Alpha. Should I set up a new question and see if it results better?

Comment: Whether you use the function $x+\lceil -x\rceil=(x \mod 1)$ or $x-\lceil x\rceil=1-(x\mod 1) $ does not make a big difference: if you plug in $n\alpha$ for an irrational $\alpha$ like $\log_2\frac34$ you will get a sequence equidistributed in $[0,1]$. How good your convergence is probably depends on how irrational $\alpha$ is. And no, I see no reason to start a new question: just edit this one if you wish to add information.

Comment: Original summation equation using mod and simplified a bit would produce: $\frac{2^{-\frac{n\log\frac{4}{3}}{\log2}\pmod1} + 2^{\frac{n \log\frac{4}{3}}{\log2}\pmod1}}{2}$ What would it take to prove the arithmetic mean of the set to be $\frac{1}{log2}$?

Comment: The equidistribution theorem in the integral form?

Comment: Now I see. There is even mod 1 in the Khinchin identity. Looks very similar.

Comment: Can you please fill up some gaps from my answers equations to your integral equation? I'd like to accept the answer after that.

Comment: To me it looks good now. Interesting is the behaviour of the accumulated value, because at times it is closer to expected value, at times it goes further. Maybe phasing toward and offward. So far I have been familiar only with stably increasing rational approximations.